Polynomial ring quotient by an ideal generated by an irreducible polynomial
Question: Suppose that a commutative ring $E$ containing $R$ as a subfield with the same unity and an element $a \in E$ is a zero of an irreducible polynomial $r(x) \in R[x]$. Is $ R[x]/\langle r(x) \rangle \cong R[a] $ always true?
Let $ R $ be a commutative ring with unity, and let $ r(x) $ be an irreducible polynomial in $ R[x] $. Suppose there exists a commutative ring $ E $ containing $ R $ with the same unity and an element $ a \in E $ such that $ r(a) = 0 $ in $ E $. Let $ I = \langle r(x) \rangle \subseteq R[x] $, the ideal generated by $ r(x) $. Define $ R[a] $ as the image of the evaluation homomorphism of $R[x]$ into $ E $ at $ x = a $.
Is it true that $ R[x]/I \cong R[a] $ in all cases?
I understand that if $ r(x) $ is monic, we can apply polynomial long division and the isomorphism theorem to establish the isomorphism. However, when $ r(x) $ is not monic, complications arise. The leading coefficient of $r(x) $ might not be a unit or could even be a zero divisor. Could this prevent $ R[x]/I $ from being isomorphic to $ R[a] $?
Any insights or counterexamples would be greatly appreciated.
Let us recall some definitions for precision. A commutative ring is a ring with unity in which the multiplication commutative. An invertible element is called a unit. Two elements $a$ and $b$ are said to be associated if there is a unit $u$ such that $b=ua$. A non-zero element $d$ is called a divisor of another element $k$ is there is $q$ such that $k=qd$. For an element $k$, a proper divisor of $k$ is a non-unit divisor which is not associated with $k$. A non-zero, non-unit element $r$ is said to be irreducible if it does not admit any proper divisor.

Can’t you just take $a=x+\langle r(x)\rangle$?

@cqfd Can you be more specific?

The answer is negative. The assertion fails even in an integral domain.
The following example is from my colleague.
Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[i \sqrt{3}]$ and consider an irreducible polynomial $f(x) = 2x-i \sqrt{3}+1$. Let $\omega$ be a zero of $g(x) = x^2+x+1 \in R[x]$. Note that $f(\omega) = 0$ over $R[\omega] = \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$.
Consider the evaluation homomorphism $e:R[x] \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, $p(x) \mapsto p(\alpha)$. Since the homomorphism is epic, the assertion $R[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle \simeq R[\omega]$ amounts to $\langle f(x) \rangle = \ker e$.
However, while $g(x) \in \ker e$, we observe that  $g(x) \not \in \langle f(x) \rangle $.
Therefore, $ \langle f(x) \rangle \neq \ker e $, and the isomorphism
$$
R[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle \simeq R[\omega]
$$
does not hold.
